# Dynamic SQL same from and where clause but different select clause one working one not

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I came through an job failure. In the Job PLS was called with the offcid and spool file. I checked the spool file the error was invalid numer. While running the query in PLS separately by passing the offcid I found out that the error was coming at one select query in which the offcid was passed dynamically in `where` clause.

```
where offcid = &2;
```

While checking the details further I found that there is one more identical query with respect to from and where clause only select clause differs (there is no `group by`) but that is running fine. The offcid is passed in the job as 43. On suggestion from senior developers we scanned the table and found that there is character value in offcid column for one record in source table we removed it and then the query ran fine.

One more thing I faced this error only in production environment in dev the same query under the same scenario ran fine. Does anybody have any idea what might have caused the issue? Does oracle 11g have any kind of back end checking that might have caused this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So offcid is defined as VARCHAR2 and not a numeric column? If that's the case, you'll probably want to wrap your substitution variable in quotes so that the value passed in is treated as a character as well. (Whether the column should maybe be defined as a numeric column is another matter.)

If I understand your question, you would like to know why one environment runs into the "invalid number" error in one environment and not the other, assuming both environments have the same data?

If you try comparing a string with a number, Oracle will implicitly try to convert the character value to a number first and compare the result with the number. That is, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE '1' = 1
```

will actually be evaluated as this:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE TO_NUMBER('1') = 1
```

Here the string '1' can be converted to a number and all is well.

In your case, if &2 is substituted with, say, 10, your query will be evaluated as:

```
SELECT ... where TO_NUMBER(offcid) = 10
```

The reason you can get the "invalid number" error intermittently even when the table does have offcid values that can't be converted to a number depends on whether or not Oracle actually considers a row containing a value that can't be converted to a number. This all rides on the execution plan used for the query.

Let's say you have a query like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM some_table where TO_NUMBER(offcid) = 17 AND another_column = 4
```

and let's say your offending row has offcid = 'ONE7' and another_column = 2

If Oracle does a full table scan on some_table, it will compare all of the rows and you will run into the error when it hits the row that has a value that it can't convert to a number (say 'XYZ'). But, if you have an index on another_column which Oracle decides to use first to isolate rows with another_column = 4, it won't look at the row with another_column = 2 and won't try to convert the 'XYZ' to a number and you won't get the error.

It is possible to have two environments with exactly the same data with exactly the same query but **because of different execution plans used** (database versions have been known to cause changes in the way the optimizer works which can affect the query plans) your query can run fine in one environment but fail in the other.

Does that make sense?